# OnClick hook call - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, graphql, react-hooks

I need to execute a graphQL query so my users can log out. Ideally, they would click a `logout` button and the query would execute, signing them out. However, it's not that easy.

Here's my code so far:

```js
const LOGOUT = gql`
  mutation Logout {
    logout
  }
`;

const LogoutButton = (props) => {
  const logout = () => {
    useMutation<Record<string, any>>(LOGOUT);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
  )
};
```

I'm getting the following error message: `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

I'm sorry for such a rookie question, but I'm stuck. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Is the function firing? Is there an error? What about this isn't working? Can you give us some context?

Comment: Sorry about that! I just updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Can you add the entire component's code?

Comment: You've got a use-hook within a callback function, that's a big nogo and certainly introduces some errors, although I'm not sure whether that's the cause of your issue here. Look into how ``useMutation`` works exactly, but it's certainly meant to be placed within you component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const LOGOUT = gql`
  mutation Logout {
    logout
  }
`;

const LogoutButton = (props) => {
  const [logout] = useMutation<Record<string, any>>(LOGOUT);

  return (
    <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
  )

};
```

A hook, aka something that begins with `use...()`, is always meant to be placed top-level in your functional component, never within a callback. In this case, `useMutation` already returns your function (specifically, wrapped inside an array).

Comment: My man! I had a small issue with the onClick. If it helps others, this is error message I got:

`Type '(options?: MutationFunctionOptions<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined) => Promise<FetchResult<any, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>>' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'. Types of parameters 'options' and 'event' are incompatible.`

I solved this by wrapping the event handler in a fat arrow function:
`onClick={() => {logout(); }}`

Answer (score 0):

The error is the answer. Your component here is not a functional component. It's likely you forgot to wrap your logic in to a component. Try this:

```js
const LOGOUT = gql`
  mutation Logout {
    logout
  }
`;

const LogoutButton = (props) => {
  const logout = () => {
    useMutation<Record<string, any>>(LOGOUT);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
  )

};
```

Then call `LogoutButton` where you want your button to appear.

Note: I didn't list imports here as I'm assuming you know what you need to import to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I left out that it's wrapped in a FC, so it currently looks like your answer. Sorry I left that out. My brain is fried after a long day.

The problem seems to be with the function `logout`. The hook wants to be called outside of any additional functions. It wants to be at the top, level. It guess that's how to say it. 

It wants to be like this:

```
const LOGOUT = gql`
  mutation Logout {
    logout
  }
`;

const LogoutButton = () => {
useMutation<Record<string, any>>(LOGOUT);
....

}
```

Comment: We need to see the whole component then. `useMutation` isn't being called from a FC or it wouldn't be throwing this error. OR there's another part of your script throwing this error.

Comment: `useMutation` is a hook and CAN'T be called at the top level.